# Magento upgrade error 2.4.5 in php 8.1

Tags: setup-di-compile, magento2.4.4, version-upgrade

I am facing after an issue after upgrading version magneto 2.4.3 to 2.4.5
When I run this command I got error

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Zend_Config::count() should either be compatible with Countable

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us that your magento 2.4.5 is running fine or not. I want to use Magento 2.4.5 for my site?

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade again because your upgrade failed.

Solution 1: Update the composer.json file specifically the require-dev section with what is written here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/composer.json

Then remove `vendor` folder and run the following commands:

```
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Solution2: Do the following steps:

1. STAY IN PHP 7.4
2. composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
3. composer update
4. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* ; bin/magento setup:upgrade
5. composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 --no-update
6. composer update
7. CHANGE TO PHP 8.1
8. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* ; bin/magento setup:upgrade; bin/magento setup:di:compile

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35306

Comment: I did but got same error again

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check.

Comment: I tried both solutions but got same an error

Comment: You can take a look at the github issue, some suggestion there maybe help you: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35306